# How to truncate the text returned for a column in a MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database that I am running simple SELECT queries on (for quick diagnostics/analysis - since I am not running phpmyadmin on the server - for security reasons).

I would like to be able to truncate the returned data using something like this:

```
select id, LEFT(full_name, 32), age FROM user
```

where user is a table that contains the columns id, full_name and age

I tried the above statement and it didn't work. anyone knows how to do this?

**[Edit]**

Sorry, when I said it dosen't work, I mean mySQL simply returns the STRING "LEFT(full_name, 32)" as an alias for the column 'full_name' and outputs the field value - which in this case, can be as long as 256 chars.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What result are you getting, and what do you expect to get? Do you need to set an alias select id, LEFT(full_name, 32) as full_name, age FROM user to acces sit in your code?

Comment: In my testing, the code shown above works as-is in current mysql. I don't know if this was a bug at the time question was asked.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
select id, SUBSTRING(full_name,1, 32), age FROM user
```

Quoting [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

> For all forms of [`SUBSTRING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.

Comment: As pointed out by Mark Baker in the comments above, an alias on the SUBSTRING would be a good idea

Comment: more details about `SUBSTRING` here : http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html

Comment: How is this any different than what OP did with `Left`? `... SUBSTRING(full_name, 1, 32), ...` is equivalent to `... Left(full_name, 32), ...`. Or at the time this answer was given, was mysql `Left` buggy?  Anyway, OP's original code works for me.

Comment: It was 9 years ago, maybe left() did not exist yet

Answer (score 4):

```sql
select id, SUBSTR(full_name, 1, 32), age FROM user;
```

OR

```sql
select id, SUBSTRING(full_name, 1, 32), age FROM user;
```

OR

```sql
select id, SUBSTRING(full_name, FROM 1 FOR 32), age FROM user
```

**Note**: `SUBSTR()` is a synonym for `SUBSTRING()`.

found [on mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, SUBSTRING(full_name,1, 32), age FROM user
```